# jquery/php hide/show didn't work when i view my page with an id

Tags: php, jquery

i have a form with a jquery script that show/hide some divs (private form content and company form content). When i view my page, i can choose between private forms and company forms with radio buttons. but, if i view the page with an id (e.g. mypage?id=1), the content will not show until i click on the right radio button.

Here is my code:

```js
$(function () {
$('#company_fields').hide();
$('#private_fields').hide();

$("input[name=art]:radio").change(function () {

    if ($('input[name=art]:checked').val() == "company") {
        $('#private_fields').hide();
        $('#company_fields').show();

    } else if ($('input[name=art]:checked').val() == "private") {
        $('#private_fields').show();
        $('#company_fields').hide();

    }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <label for="company" class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name="art" id="comp_yes" value="private"> private
   </label>
                           
 <label for="company" class="radio-inline">
   <input type="radio" name="art" id="comp_no" value="company"> company
   </label>
</form>


<div id="private_fields">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="textinput" class="control-label">Street</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" id="street" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="company_fields">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="textinput" class="control-label">Company</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```

My input for the radio buttons look like this (the code editor dont understood php):

```
<input type="radio" name="art" id="comp_no" value="private" <?php if (isset($_GET['id'])) {echo $row->art == "private" ? 'checked="checked"' : "";}?>> private
```

i hope anyone can help me that the content show until i view my page with an id, too. The right radio button is checked, but the content will not show up.. everything is wrong with my query code :/

sorry for bad english..

Comment: Not the problem, only a misused [`for`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-label-for) attribute in the `<label>` tags: _"...If the attribute is specified, the attribute's value **must be the ID of a labelable element** in the same Document as the label element..."_ ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change event is not triggered while the page is loading. You could trigger the event manually after you defined it.

```
$(function () {
    $('#company_fields').hide();
    $('#private_fields').hide();

    $("input[name=art]:radio").change(function () {

        if ($('input[name=art]:checked').val() == "company") {
            $('#private_fields').hide();
            $('#company_fields').show();

        } else if ($('input[name=art]:checked').val() == "private") {
            $('#private_fields').show();
            $('#company_fields').hide();

        }
    }).trigger('change');

});
```

Or you could directly hide/show the div by PHP.

Comment: You can add the `.change()` directly after the `.change(function() { ... })`. No need to query the DOM for the radio input twice. And, imho, I would suggest to use `.trigger("change")` to make it more obvious what your intention is.